# Usage stats of different Ubuntu versions

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04

At the time of writing this question, Ubuntu 22.04 is almost out. I am curious about how fast the developers will migrate from older versions (potentially from 18.04 LTS) to the new LTS. This is important for me to decide which Ubuntu version I should target with my application.

The best would be some statistics about the usage of the different Linux distros **and versions**, potentially with time scale. There are a few charts and list out (e.g., https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=trending) but I could not find any statistics that go down to the distro's version level.

What is the best or "official" source to get this information from?